# Can I monitor web site activity with my Netgear router?

Tags: router, logging

I have a wireless router and want to know what web sites my users open. I mean I want to see the logs. It is a Netgear router and two people use it. If you guys know any software that can do this, please let me know.

Comment: While you opened a large can of legal and ethical concern worms, what you describe is only partially possible. By using ssl, your logs would be reduced to domain names, and with an encrypted vpn, your logs will only show the vpn server.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend giving DD WRT a shot. DD WRT is a custom firmware for routers which unlocks many new features which the manufacturer wouldn't normally let you use.

I think you will find it easier to find info on logging DD WRT than your specific router.

Have a look here: [www.dd-wrt.com/](http://www.dd-wrt.com/)

Comment: It's not that User-Freindly thing , Anyother softwares ?

Comment: You could also try tomato: http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato

Answer (score 0):

Hi please go through the link,
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110125212405AAfwnIt
First of all check your router manual and confirm that whether you router has feature to store the logs, if so it can be configured by accessing the router console. IOS based routers will have this capability, im not sure whether this facility is given for tiny wired / wireless routers.